# C#, SQL Server, Linq-to-SQL - cannot find item in query results (list of classes)

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, class, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a list of class objects that I gather from a database. I am able to use a Linq-to-SQL class in order to use Linq to make a list of class objects.

I am able to look up things in the list however it fails when I look up something that is not in the list (null error exception). I would like to test for null or somehow figure out if my item is not in the list but

```
q.Find(x => (x.fid1 == "abc123")).fid1 = "9454a3" == null
```

generates a null error exception. This is my first time using the Linq-to-SQL class so any input as to how I am using it would be welcome as well.

```
class TestClass
{
    public class FIDClass
    {
        public System.String fid1 { get; set; }
        public System.String fid2 { get; set; }
        public System.Int32 fid3 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    { 
        //  linq to SQL class
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var q = (from dbfile in db.GetTable<DataTable>()
                 where dbfilefid3  == 15
                 select new FIDClass
                 {
                     fid1 = dbfile.fid1,
                     fid2 = dbfile.fid2,
                     fid3 = (int) dbfile.fid3
                 }).ToList<FIDClass>();

        // if it's found, the following works fine
        // if it's not found, I get a null error exception on the if stmt

        if (q.Find(x => (x.fid1 == "abc123")).fid1 == "abc123" )    
            { MessageBox.Show("Found");
            }
    }
}
```

Any help, thoughts, feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my iPad, so can't test this out.
Depending on version of .net you could try null coalesce

```
    if (q.Any(x => (x?.fid1 == "abc123")) )
```

Otherwise,

if (q.Any(x => x!=null && (x.fid1 == "abc123"))

Comment: This works. I am considering looking at Entity Framework.

Comment: It was quite late, last night, I don't think you need the  null check. The any should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for null as below:

```
if (q.Find(x => x.fid1 == "abc123") != null ) 
        { MessageBox.Show("Found");
        }
else
        { MessageBox.Show("NOT Found");
        }
```

Please mark as answered if that solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Rajnieesh -- good catch.  That happened while simplifying my code so it does not solve my problem as I originally did have the ==.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's 2017 don't use Linq to SQL it's been depreciated for a while now.
Second your query is not optimized at all. You are pulling all the data from the server with the ToList method that is bad what you want to use is IQueriables to do the query operations.
And the problem you are having is that the find method returns a null if no object is found so use the Any method if you just want to check if there is an object that satisfies the condition `Any((x)=>x.fid1 == "abc123")`

Comment: Thanks.  So just do a regular query and use the reader to populate the class list or maybe you can give a simple example of using IQueriables.  I will Google it right now.  Are you saying I shouldn't be using Linq to SQL classes?

Comment: Use [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) it's a modern version of Linq to SQL. And for IQueriable here is a [Link](http://haroldrv.com/2015/02/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-iqueryable/)

Comment: Thank you Filip!  I have been somewhat afraid of Entity Framework because it seems to add a lot of overhead.  I will look at your link.

Comment: Don't be it's more or less the same as Linq to SQL. And with VS it's fast to get started, There are templates that will build most of what you need to get started.